# What is the equivalent of the "President's Council on Sports, Fitness & Nutrition" in other G20 countries such as China?

Tags: russian-federation, china, government, international, public-health

> The President’s Council on Sports, Fitness & Nutrition (PCSFN) is a
> federal advisory committee that aims to promote healthy eating and
> physical activity for all Americans, regardless of background or
> ability.

https://health.gov/our-work/nutrition-physical-activity/presidents-council

Does such an analog exist in PR China,etc?

Comment: [Sport England](https://www.sportengland.org/) is the equivalent in England, the largest part of the UK; [SportScotland](https://sportscotland.org.uk/) and other agencies cover the rest of the UK. Are you just wanting a list for all the G20 countries? In Germany I think it's at a Land (state/region) level rather than Federal (national).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In China, physical activities for all Chinese are regulated under a plan called the "National Exercise Plan" that is directed by the State Council--see [this](http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2021-08/03/content_5629218.htm). Healthy Eating is the responsibility of the National Bureau of Disease Control and Prevention, which published an [advisory](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%B1%85%E6%B0%91%E8%86%B3%E9%A3%9F%E6%8C%87%E5%8D%97%282016%29/19667497?fromtitle=%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%B1%85%E6%B0%91%E8%86%B3%E9%A3%9F%E6%8C%87%E5%8D%97&fromid=4358618) authored by the Chinese Nutrition Society

Sorry, but you would have to translate the source material yourself because it is all in Chinese. One is a government document and the other is a Chinese version of wiki